# Asp.net share session between ASP.NET applications

Tags: asp.net, session, share

I have 2 asp.net applications , I want to share session between the two applications.
on my localhost i added 2 entries in the host file for the 2 subdomains say (test1.test.com) and (test2.test.com).
In each of the applications I changed the **web.config** with

```
<httpCookies domain=".test.com">
```

also I changed the **machine key** as following

```
<machineKey validationKey="3FC58E938A92B609AB264D18C4A494CEB2A01100C7FE71AC6B41DD5372458D8265C5D06E72CC67F1F0AD58B8713DFDB0A8058861D39F47B5AA65310C8C45107D" decryptionKey="C24521F47AEAB67CC40F679632975C91AC0FCBD9A2E173B3" validation="SHA1" />
```

but I did not get the expected result (session is not shared between the 2 applications)

did I missed something, Help me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup a [ASP.NET Session State Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732412(v=ws.10).aspx). [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/lichen/sharing-session-state-over-multiple-asp-net-applications-with-asp-net-state-server) is a good blog post about this task. Also, you can use [SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317604) to keep sessions.

Comment: I tried ASP.NET Session State Server, Still it is not working . I'm using IIS7